# Login form with two different condition

Tags: php, authentication

I have a login page. Admin A for main branch and other Admin B, C and for branch B, C and D. Admin A can login to all branch while Admin B, C and D only can login into their own branch. But now what I can do is all admin only can login into their own branch. How can I do it so Admin A also can login into branch B, C and D?

This is my code.

```
if($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'] &&  $_POST['txtbranch']) {
$username  =  $_POST['username'];
$password  =  $_POST['password'];
$txtbranch =  $_POST['txtbranch'];

$hash_pass = $password;

$query = mysqli_query("select * from sysfile where username='".$username."' and password='".$hash_pass."' and branchid='".$txtbranch."' limit 1");

$count_user = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count_user==1)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['userid'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['pin'] = $row['pin'];
    $_SESSION['branchid'] = $_POST['txtbranch'];
    header("location:dashboard.php?success=1");
}else{                        
        $error = 'Incorrect Username, Password and Branch.';    
    }
}
```

Comment: `Admin A` is a username? You are open to SQL injections and should have hashed passwords.

Comment: Do you actually hash? Changing a variable name is not hashing..

Comment: It may sound discouraging to you. Please use prepared statement and learn how to hash your password before moving forward: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: show verification login kode. i mean like this if($_SESSION['userid'] == false){

Answer (score 1):

- add type field in your login table in database
- then after add all admin and set type like Admin A=1, And B,C,D=2
- now set condition in login page

­

```
if ($type == 1) {
    //Admin A login
} else {
    // Another Admin Login
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go and add a table for the user's rights

```
┌──────┬──────┐
│userid│branch│
├──────┼──────┤
│ 1    │ A    │
│ 1    │ B    │
│ 1    │ C    │
│ 1    │ D    │
│ 2    │ B    │
│ 2    │ C    │
│ 2    │ D    │
└──────┴──────┘
```

Then you can emit an SQL statement like the following

```
SELECT *
    FROM users, userrights 
    WHERE users.userid=userrights.userid
      AND users.username=@username
      AND users.password=@hashed_pass
    LIMIT 1
```

This SQL query selects all columns (better select columns explicitly! `SELECT userid, username, pin, branchid FROM ...`) from the joined tables `users` and `userrights` (renamed the tables for clarity). The latter holds the user's rights for the tables. Filtered and limited as your original query with the slight difference that I've used SQL parameters to prevent injections.

With that query you can keep your

```
$count_user = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count_user==1)
{
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace branch_id with role so that it can be easy to understand other people also.
You have to insert a flag in database naming as a role.
If role is 1 - That in Your case (A -Main branch)
If role is 2 - That in Your case (B,C,D - Other branch)

let's say your database sturcture would be like

```
id | username | password | role |
---------------------------------
1  | A        | 123      | 1
---------------------------------
2  | B        | 1111     | 2
---------------------------------
3  | C        | 2323     | 2
---------------------------------
4  | D        | 1782     | 2
```

I do not prefer plain text password to store in database, this is just for example purpose.
Your code will look like these :

```
if($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'] &&  $_POST['txtbranch']) 
{
$username  =  $_POST['username'];
$password  =  $_POST['password'];
$txtbranch =  $_POST['txtbranch'];

$hash_pass = $password;

$query = mysqli_query("select * from sysfile where username='".$username."' and password='".$hash_pass."' and branchid='".$txtbranch."' limit 1");

$count_user = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count_user==1)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $role  = $row['role'];
    if($role == 1)
    {
      //that is A then set the session and redirect to A dashboard
    }
    else if($role ==2)
    {
      //that is B,C and D then set the session and redirect to there respective dashbaord
    }
    else
    {
      //whatever action you want
    }
}
else
{                        
        $error = 'Incorrect Username, Password and Branch.';    
}
}
```

Comment: I will try this first.

Answer (score 0):

I already solve my problem and this is my final code.

```
if($_POST['SUBMIT']=='Sign In')
{
if($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'] &&  $_POST['txtbranch']) 
{   
    $username  = $_POST['username'];
    $password  = $_POST['password'];
    $txtbranch = $_POST['txtbranch'];

    $query_callbranch=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM sysfile WHERE USERNAME='$username' ")or die(mysqli_error());
    while($rowcallbranch=mysqli_fetch_array($query_callbranch))
    {
        $pin = $rowcallbranch['pin'];

        if($pin == '9' && $username == 'admin')
        {
            $query = mysqli_query("select * from sysfile where username='".$username."' and password='".$password."' limit 1");

            $count_user = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            if($count_user==1)
            {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

                $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['userid'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION['pin'] = $row['pin'];
                $_SESSION['branchid'] = $_POST['txtbranch'];
                header("location:dashboard.php?success=1");
            }else{
                $error = 'Incorrect Username dan Password.';    
            }
        }

        if($pin == '0')
        {
            $query = mysqli_query("select * from sysfile where username='".$username."' and password='".$hash_pass."' and branchid='".$txtbranch."' limit 1");

            $count_user = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            if($count_user==1)
            {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

                $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['userid'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION['pin'] = $row['pin'];
                $_SESSION['branchid'] = $_POST['txtbranch'];
                header("location:dashboard.php?success=1");
            }else{
                    $error = 'Incorrect Username, Password and Branch.';    
            }
        }               
    }
}
```

}